# Domain Auction: bidding against myself?

Tags: domains, domain-backorder

I backordered a domain name that was on "Pending Delete" status, using SnapName.com, NameJet.com and Pool.com.

All went fine, and now two of those services sent me an email telling me the domain was ready for me to start bidding.

However it's funny because when I log into Snapname.com I find that my rival is myself - under the other username I created on Namejet.com.

What to do now? Both of "us" are offering 79$.

Should I outbid my alter-ego with 1$, or just wait - and it will be automatically assigned to me in Snapname.com?

Snapname.com says that "*Note that if multiple equal bids are received, the first bidder wins the opening bid*" but that's it.

Thanks for any clarification guys, it's the first time I do this.

Comment: This explains the situation: both services merged forces recently this 2016: http://domainnamewire.com/2016/04/11/namejet-snapnames-pending-delete-domain-names/

Comment: Personally, I would avoid these online scam artists and go with a legitimate registrar that offers the same services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I guess a double congrats is in order! It sounds like if you don't do anything whichever account you backordered the domain from first will get it. I would recommend contacting Snapnames and/or Namejet for clarification just in case.

Comment: I finally outbid myself with 5$ and won the auction, then contacted them, and they refunded the 5$ to my credit card.